# Solution of non linear coupled equations by using shooting, block and StartingInitialConditions

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

My code is not giving out put. Moreover i do not know how to copy paste this code from my note book. is there any easiest way to paste here. I m plotting graph for the different values of R.  I have also to plot for the differnt values of epsilon......... can we predict values given in block. ............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................ kindly guide

```
eqn1=(1+1/\[Beta])((1+\[Epsilon]-\[Epsilon] \[Theta][y]) f''''[y]-\[Epsilon] f''[y] \[Theta]''[y]-2 \[Epsilon] f'''[y] \[Theta]'[y])+\[Alpha] (y f'''[y]+3 f''[y])+R (f[y] f'''[y]-f'[y] f''[y])- M^2 f''[y]==0;
eqn2=(1+NN)\[Theta]''[y]+Pr  (\[Alpha](m \[Theta][y]+y \[Theta]'[y])+ R(f[y] \[Theta]'[y]-m f'[y] \[Theta][y]))==0;
bcs1={f[-1]==A,f'[-1]==0, f[1]==1, f'[1]==0 };
bcs2={\[Theta][-1]==1, \[Theta][1]==0};
f1=Block [{\[Beta]=0.5, \[Epsilon]=1.5, Pr=1, M=1,NN=2,R=-5,m=1, \[Alpha]=0.5,A=-0.2},
First[NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, bcs1, bcs2},
{f[\[Eta]],f'[\[Eta]], f''[\[Eta]],f'''[\[Eta]], \[Theta][\[Eta]],\ 
[Theta]'[\[Eta]]}, {\[Eta],-1,1},
Method->{"Shooting",  "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
{{f[-1]==A,f[-1]==0,f'[-1]==0, f''[-1]==0,f'''[-1]==0,\[Theta][-1]==1,\ 
[Theta][-1]==0,\[Theta]'[-1]==0}}}
]]
];
TableForm[
Table[{\[Eta],{f[\[Eta]]/.f1}, {f'[\[Eta]]/.f1}, {f''[\[Eta]]/.f1},{\[Theta] 
[\[Eta]]/.f1},{\[Theta]'[\[Eta]]/.f1}},{\[Eta],-1,1,0.2}], TableAlignments-> 
{Center,Center},
TableHeadings->{None,{"\[Eta]","f(\[Eta])","f'[\[Eta]]","f''[\[Eta]]","\ 
[Theta][\[Eta]]","\[Theta]'[\[Eta]]"}},TableSpacing->{1,5}]
f2=Block [{\[Beta]=0.5, \[Epsilon]=1.5, Pr=1, M=1,NN=2,R=-2.5,m=1, \ 
[Alpha]=0.5,A=-0.2},
First[NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, bcs1, bcs2},
{f[\[Eta]],f'[\[Eta]], f''[\[Eta]],f'''[\[Eta]], \[Theta][\[Eta]],\ 
[Theta]'[\[Eta]]}, {\[Eta],-1,1},
Method->{"Shooting",  "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
{{f[-1]==A,f[-1]==0,f'[-1]==0, f''[-1]==0,f'''[-1]==0,\[Theta][-1]==1,\ 
[Theta][-1]==0,\[Theta]'[-1]==0}}}
]]
 ];
 TableForm[
 Table[{\[Eta],{f[\[Eta]]/.f2}, {f'[\[Eta]]/.f2}, {f''[\[Eta]]/.f2},{\ 
 [Theta][\[Eta]]/.f2},{\[Theta]'[\[Eta]]/.f2}},{\[Eta],-1,1,0.2}], 
 TableAlignments->{Center,Center},
 TableHeadings->{None,{"\[Eta]","f(\[Eta])","f'[\[Eta]]","f''[\[Eta]]","\ 
 [Theta][\[Eta]]","\[Theta]'[\[Eta]]"}},TableSpacing->{1,5}]
 f3=Block [{\[Beta]=0.5, \[Epsilon]=1.5, Pr=1, M=1,NN=2,R=0,m=1, \ 
 [Alpha]=0.5,A=-0.2},
 First[NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, bcs1, bcs2},
 {f[\[Eta]],f'[\[Eta]], f''[\[Eta]],f'''[\[Eta]], \[Theta][\[Eta]],\ 
 [Theta]'[\[Eta]]}, {\[Eta],-1,1},
 Method->{"Shooting",  "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
 {{f[-1]==A,f[-1]==0,f'[-1]==0, f''[-1]==0,f'''[-1]==0,\[Theta][-1]==1,\ 
 [Theta][-1]==0,\[Theta]'[-1]==0}}}
 ]]
 ];
 TableForm[
 Table[{\[Eta],{f[\[Eta]]/.f3}, {f'[\[Eta]]/.f3}, {f''[\[Eta]]/.f3},{\ 
[Theta] 
[\[Eta]]/.f3},{\[Theta]'[\[Eta]]/.f3}},{\[Eta],-1,1,0.2}], TableAlignments-> 
{Center,Center},
TableHeadings->{None,{"\[Eta]","f(\[Eta])","f'[\[Eta]]","f''[\[Eta]]","\ 
[Theta][\[Eta]]","\[Theta]'[\[Eta]]"}},TableSpacing->{1,5}]
f4=Block [{\[Beta]=0.5, \[Epsilon]=1.5, Pr=1, M=1,NN=2,R=2.5,m=1, \ 
[Alpha]=0.5,A=-0.2},
First[NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, bcs1, bcs2},
{f[\[Eta]],f'[\[Eta]], f''[\[Eta]],f'''[\[Eta]], \[Theta][\[Eta]],\ 
[Theta]'[\[Eta]]}, {\[Eta],-1,1},
Method->{"Shooting",  "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
{{f[-1]==A,f[-1]==0,f'[-1]==0, f''[-1]==0,f'''[-1]==0,\[Theta][-1]==1,\ 
[Theta][-1]==0,\[Theta]'[-1]==0}}}
]]
];
TableForm[
Table[{\[Eta],{f[\[Eta]]/.f4}, {f'[\[Eta]]/.f4}, {f''[\[Eta]]/.f4},{\[Theta] 
[\[Eta]]/.f4},{\[Theta]'[\[Eta]]/.f4}},{\[Eta],-1,1,0.2}], TableAlignments-> 
{Center,Center},
TableHeadings->{None,{"\[Eta]","f(\[Eta])","f'[\[Eta]]","f''[\[Eta]]","\ 
[Theta][\[Eta]]","\[Theta]'[\[Eta]]"}},TableSpacing->{1,5}]
f5=Block [{\[Beta]=0.5, \[Epsilon]=1.5, Pr=1, M=1,NN=2,R=5,m=1, \ 
[Alpha]=0.5,A=-0.2},
First[NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, bcs1, bcs2},
{f[\[Eta]],f'[\[Eta]], f''[\[Eta]],f'''[\[Eta]], \[Theta][\[Eta]],\ 
[Theta]'[\[Eta]]}, {\[Eta],-1,1},
Method->{"Shooting",  "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
{{f[-1]==A,f[-1]==0,f'[-1]==0, f''[-1]==0,f'''[-1]==0,\[Theta][-1]==1,\ 
[Theta][-1]==0,\[Theta]'[-1]==0}}}
]]
];
TableForm[
Table[{\[Eta],{f[\[Eta]]/.f5}, {f'[\[Eta]]/.f5}, {f''[\[Eta]]/.f5},{\[Theta] 
[\[Eta]]/.f5},{\[Theta]'[\[Eta]]/.f5}},{\[Eta],-1,1,0.2}], TableAlignments-> 
{Center,Center},
 TableHeadings->{None,{"\[Eta]","f(\[Eta])","f'[\[Eta]]","f''[\[Eta]]","\ 
[Theta][\[Eta]]","\[Theta]'[\[Eta]]"}},TableSpacing->{1,5}]
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
Plot[Evaluate[{{f[\[Eta]]}/.f1,f[\[Eta]]/.f2,f[\[Eta]]/.f3,f[\[Eta]]/.f4,f[\ 
[Eta]]/.f5}],
{\[Eta],-1,1},ImageSize->500,PlotRange->All,
PlotStyle->{{Dotted,Black},{DotDashed,Red},{Dashed,Green},{Blue}},Axes-> 
{False,False},
Frame->True,FrameLabel->{Style["\[Eta]",Italic,Black],Style["f(\ 
[Eta])",Italic,Black]},
PlotLegend->{"R=-5","R=-2.5", "R=0","R=2.5","R=5"},LegendPosition-> 
{-0.1,-0.0},
LegendShadow->{0,0},LegendBackground->White,LegendSize->{0.3,0.4}]
Plot[Evaluate[{{f'[\[Eta]]}/.f1,f'[\[Eta]]/.f2,f'[\[Eta]]/.f3,f'[\ 
[Eta]]/.f4,f'[\[Eta]]/.f5}],
{\[Eta],-1,1},ImageSize->500,PlotRange->All,
PlotStyle->{{Dotted,Black},{DotDashed,Black},{Dashed,Brown},{Gray}},Axes-> 
{False,False},
Frame->True,FrameLabel->{Style["\[Eta]",Italic,Black],Style["f'(\ 
[Eta])",Italic,Black]},
PlotLegend->{"R=-5","R=-2.5", "R=0","R=2.5","R=5"},LegendPosition-> 
{-0.1,-0.0},
LegendShadow->{0,0},LegendBackground->White,LegendSize->{0.3,0.4}]
Plot[Evaluate[{{\[Theta][\[Eta]]}/.f1,\[Theta][\[Eta]]/.f2,\[Theta][\ 
[Eta]]/.f3,\[Theta][\[Eta]]/.f4,\[Theta][\[Eta]]/.f5}],
{\[Eta],-1,1},ImageSize->500,PlotRange->All,
PlotStyle->{{Dotted,Black},{DotDashed,Black},{Dashed,Brown},{Gray}},Axes-> 
{False,False},
Frame->True,FrameLabel->{Style["\[Eta]",Italic,Black],Style["\[Theta](\ 
[Eta])",Italic,Black]},
PlotLegend->{"R=-5","R=-2.5", "R=0","R=2.5","R=5"},LegendPosition-> 
{-0.1,-0.0},
LegendShadow->{0,0},LegendBackground->White,LegendSize->{0.3,0.4}]
```

The above code is giving message that my dependent varibles are more than equations. here is the copied message 
NDSolve::underdet

Comment: Equations eqn1 and eqn2 depend on `y`, and you call the solver with the $\eta $ variable. Fix the whole code. Replace $\eta $ in `NDSolve[]` with `y`.

Answer (score 2):

In version 12, a solution can be obtained without specifying a method. It is only necessary to replace $\eta $ with `y` in `NDSolve`.

```
eqn1 = (1 + 
       1/\[Beta]) ((1 + \[Epsilon] - \[Epsilon] \[Theta][y]) f''''[
         y] - \[Epsilon] f''[y] \[Theta]''[y] - 
       2 \[Epsilon] f'''[y] \[Theta]'[y]) + \[Alpha] (y f'''[y] + 
       3 f''[y]) + R (f[y] f'''[y] - f'[y] f''[y]) - M^2 f''[y] == 0;
eqn2 = (1 + NN) \[Theta]''[y] + 
    Pr (\[Alpha] (m \[Theta][y] + y \[Theta]'[y]) + 
       R (f[y] \[Theta]'[y] - m f'[y] \[Theta][y])) == 0;
bcs1 = {f[-1] == A, f'[-1] == 0, f[1] == 1, f'[1] == 0};
bcs2 = {\[Theta][-1] == 1, \[Theta][1] == 0};
f1 = Block[{\[Beta] = 0.5, \[Epsilon] = 1.5, Pr = 1, M = 1, NN = 2, 
   R = -5, m = 1, \[Alpha] = 0.5, A = -0.2}, 
  First[NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, bcs1, bcs2}, {f[y], f'[y], f''[y], 
     f'''[y], \[Theta][y], \[Theta]'[y]}, {y, -1, 1}]]]
Plot[Evaluate[{f[y] /. f1, f'[y] /. f1, \[Theta][y] /. f1}], {y, -1, 
  1}, ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Dotted, Black}, {DotDashed, Red}, {Dashed, 
    Green}, {Blue}}, Axes -> {False, False}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["\[Eta]", Italic, Black], 
   Style["f(\[Eta]), f'(\[Eta]), \[Theta](\[Eta])", Italic, Black]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: dear thanks allot. your given code is in mathematica 12 and its giving output at epsilon=1.5 but i am facing another problem while i have changed eta by y. code is not not running for the higher values of epsilon in mathematica 11. Kindly help in this version

Comment: Sorry, I only have versions 8, 9, 10 and 12. I'll see what can be done with growth epsilon. Is this a heat transfer problem?

Comment: yes its a heat transfer problem